# C# HttpClient weird error

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code which runs with no issues on Windows Phone 8, but running on Windows  8 results in error.

Error:

```
Exception received while submitting the payload:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FooProject.HTTPHelper.<SubmitRequestToMobileAnalytics>d__a.MoveNext() in c:\Users\foo_000\Documents\GitHub\FooProject\HttpHelper.cs:line 135
Inner Exception is:    at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<GetRequestStreamCallback>b__6(Task task)
```

Code:

```
string jsonPayload = "<<<Some JSON Payload>>>";
 using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {

                try
                {
                    //Converting the JSON payload as GZipped byte array    
                    byte[] payload = CompressAsByte(jsonPayload);
                    if (payload != null)
                    {
                        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Config.Instance().TrackingServer);
                        request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(payload);
                        request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                        request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                        return (int)response.StatusCode;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }

                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {

                    Logger.Log("Exception received while submitting the payload: " + e.StackTrace);
                    if (e.InnerException != null)
                    {
                        Logger.Log("Inner Exception is: " + e.InnerException.StackTrace);

                    }

                    return 0;

                }
            }
```

For Windows Phone 8 App, I am referencing Microsoft HttpClient from the NuGet repository.
For Windows 8, already the packages System.Net and System.Net.Http are visible to me.

For some reason, the same code running on Phone works and on Windows 8 Tablet (simulator), it throws error.

Am I missing anything using HttpClient on Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code, it worked like magic.

```
request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", payload.Length.ToString());
```

I don't know why it succeeded without this line on Windows Phone 8.

But it worked.